# asp.net mvc editfortemplate in create view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

```
@model  SepiaCMSClassLib.Model.Page
<table>
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        <tr>
            <td width="300">
                @Html.EditorFor(m=>m.pagedetail)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

My model

```
public class Page
{
     public int PageID { get; set; }
     public int SortId { get; set; }
     public List<PagesDetail> pagedetail { get; set; }
}

public class PagesDetail
{
    public int PageTitle{ get; set; }
    public int PageDescription{ get; set; }
    public int LangId{ get; set; }
}
```

In my action method i am passing nothing to this view as it is the create view

```
public ActionResult Create()
{         
    return View();
}
```

The problem is that my `EditorFor()` template is loading when i pass data to it it is loading , it is not loading if i pass no data. i understand that is the default behavior. I wanted to use nested model binding ( only passing `page` model in the controller posts). `Html.Partial()` will not give the desired result of nested model binding

How can i use `EditorFor` template approach in create view?

Comment: Please post model so I can help in details.

Comment: I have posted the model as well

Comment: Firstly you have invalid html - a `<form>` element cannot be a child of a `<table>` element (you need to swap them - put the table in the form). Are you wanting to have a view where you can dynamically add new `PagesDetail` items? If so, some options [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29161481/post-a-form-array-without-successful/29161796#29161796) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28019793/submit-same-partial-view-called-multiple-times-data-to-controller/28081308#28081308)

Comment: @ Stephen Muecke ok so i would not be using the above approach for create?

Comment: @maz3tt, Not if your wanting to dynamically add multiple `PagesDetail` items in the view. The only thing you can do with your current approach is to add a fixed number of default `PagesDetail` items to the collection in the controller before you pass the model to the view.

Comment: @maz3tt: I will Suggest provide name and Id unique and self created.

Comment: one more question . i have been playing around with begincollection. what i find out that it will work in page->pagedetail scenario. but if i want to drill down like this page->pagedetail->pagesubdetail. it will not work?.

Comment: It will only create automatic binding in in page->pagedetail ? am i right?

Comment: Once you have more than one level of nesting it becomes extremely complicated when using the `BeginCollectionItem` helper. I have seen article that created another helper based on `BeginCollectionItem` to do this. I'll have a look for it later and let you know if I find it

Comment: The article I was referring to is [Editing and binding nested lists with ASP.NET MVC 2](http://www.joe-stevens.com/2011/06/06/editing-and-binding-nested-lists-with-asp-net-mvc-2/)